# JSON.NET won't deserialize class correctly

Tags: json.net, deserialization, nodatime

I am trying to make a class (that contains `NodaTime`'s `ZonedDateTime` properties) to be deserialized correctly (using JSON.NET) but it doesn't seem to work.

I am referencing and use `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` as well.

The serialization goes well and the resulting JSON is correct, but the deserialization generates wrong `ZonedDateTime` values.

Before using `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` I had written my own custom serializer for JSON.NET and I had the same problem. What I've noticed, is that the `ReadJson()` method of my custom `JsonConverter` was producing the correct deserialized `ZonedDateTime` value, but when the constructor of the class hosting the `ZonedDateTime` properties was called, the input values for the `ZonedDateTime` properties were wrong.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new ZonedTimeDetails(ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now), ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)), false);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new FullJsonSerializerSettings());
        var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ZonedTimeDetails>(json, new FullJsonSerializerSettings());
        return;
    }
}



public class FullJsonSerializerSettings : JsonSerializerSettings
{
    public FullJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new AcTypeContractResolver((MemberInfo memberInfo) => {
            if (memberInfo is PropertyInfo pi)
            {
                var methodInfo = pi.GetSetMethod(true);
                if (methodInfo == null)
                {
                    return o => false;
                }
            }
            return o => true;
        });
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;

        Converters.Add(NodaConverters.CreateZonedDateTimeConverter(DateTimeZoneProviders.Serialization));
    }
}



public class AcTypeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _predicate;
    private readonly Func<MemberInfo, Predicate<object>> _predicateFactory;

    public AcTypeContractResolver(Predicate<object> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    public AcTypeContractResolver(Func<MemberInfo, Predicate<object>> predicateFactory)
    {
        _predicateFactory = predicateFactory;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        property.Ignored = false;
        property.ShouldSerialize = _predicate ?? _predicateFactory?.Invoke(member);
        property.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        return property;
    }
}



public class ZonedTimeDetails
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public ZonedTimeDetails(ZonedDateTime zoneStart, ZonedDateTime zoneEnd, bool isOverflow = false)
    {
        ZonedStart = zoneStart;
        ZonedEnd = zoneEnd;
        IsOverflow = isOverflow;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime ZonedStart { get; private set; }
    public ZonedDateTime ZonedEnd { get; private set; }
    public bool IsOverflow { get; private set; }


    public DateTime Start => ZonedStart.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
    public DateTime End => ZonedEnd.ToDateTimeUnspecified();

    public double DurationMin => (ZonedEnd - ZonedStart).TotalMinutes;
}
```

And here is the entire project, if that helps you:
https://mega.nz/#!hFc0RAbS!teJ3Y4JHqCx1aHxUVU4kUFs30xwTTyF6QTpRB0D1Fnw

If someone has any idea what is going wrong, let me know.
From what I can tell, the problem is in the `ZonedTimeDetails` class, but I believe that this ought to be working. The property names of that class match the ctor argument names, so I cannot understand why I get wrong values in there during deserialization.

**UPDATE:**

If I make the setters for the `ZonedDateTime` properties public, it works, but I need that class to be immutable. And according to other answers on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24726390/2173353), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899593/2173353)), this constructor injection should work.

In addition to that, before I use `ZonedDateTime`, I was using `DateTime` properties in that class. And things were working without a problem with the setters private.

Comment: "In addition to that, before I use ZonedDateTime, I was using DateTime properties in that class" - I suspect you had different constructor parameter names in that case; ones that matched the property names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the parameter names in the `ZonedTimeDetails` constructor do not match up with the JSON, which you are creating from serializing that same class.  The property names have a `d` (e.g. `ZonedStart`) whereas the constructor property names do not (`zoneStart`).  So when the constructor is called, empty structs are being passed into those parameters.

To fix, just change your constructor parameter names to match the property names:

```
[JsonConstructor]
public ZonedTimeDetails(ZonedDateTime zonedStart, ZonedDateTime zonedEnd, bool isOverflow = false)
{
    ZonedStart = zonedStart;
    ZonedEnd = zonedEnd;
    IsOverflow = isOverflow;
}
```

Comment: OMG! Now I noticed I am missing a `d` in the names! :( Crap. I am so silly.